# Efficiently Importing CSV into SQL Server using Java Comparable to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to replicate the "Import Flat File" functionality of SQL Server Management Studio using Java code. This feature allows me to quickly import CSV files into a SQL Server database.
I have attempted to achieve this using Java with the JdbcTemplate and PreparedStatement, but the import process is significantly slower compared to using SQL Server Management Studio.
For instance, while SQL Server Management Studio takes around ten minutes to import a CSV file, my Java implementation using JdbcTemplate takes about three hours for the same task.
When I turn BATCH_ When the SIZE is increased, the database will report an error : connection closed by server.

My code of jdbcTemplate:

```
public class CsvImportDemo {

    private static final String CSV_FILE_PATH = "file.csv";
    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO TableA (Column1, Column2, ...) VALUES (?, ?)";
    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(/*data source */);//get by @Autowired

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILE_PATH))) {
            List<Object[]> batchArgs = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            int rowCount = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                Object[] rowArgs = new Object[]{values[0], values[1]}; 
                batchArgs.add(rowArgs);

                rowCount++;

                if (rowCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                    jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_INSERT, (PreparedStatementSetter) ps -> {
                        for (Object[] argsArray : batchArgs) {
                            ps.setObject(1, argsArray[0]);
                            ps.setObject(2, argsArray[1]);
                           
                            ps.addBatch();
                        }
                        ps.executeBatch();
                    });

                    batchArgs.clear();
                }
            }

            if (!batchArgs.isEmpty()) {
                jdbcTemplate.execute(SQL_INSERT, (PreparedStatementSetter) ps -> {
                    for (Object[] argsArray : batchArgs) {
                        ps.setObject(1, argsArray[0]);
                        ps.setObject(2, argsArray[1]);
                       
                        ps.addBatch();
                    }
                    ps.executeBatch();
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to understand the underlying principles that make SQL Server Management Studio's import process so efficient and seek advice on how to implement a Java solution that achieves similar levels of efficiency. Could someone please provide insights or suggestions on how I can optimize my Java code for faster CSV import into SQL Server?

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Optimize my Java code for faster CSV import into SQL Server

Comment: It uses BULK feature which bypasses standard inserts which you're doing. You can use SQLServerBulkCopy class from ms-jdbc driver to achieve similar (albeit slightly worse) performance. Your way generates a lot of inserts which can never match bulk performance

Comment: One thing you can do is manually build sql with a list of values as insert into xyz (...) values (1,2,3),(4,5,6) but it's still not as good as bulking